# Center a tiles canvas on a specific tile

Tags: canvas, easeljs

I have a 2d isometric map generate with canvas and EaselJS.

I have, for each tile and for the player, the x and y coordinates.

You can see a prototype of my map here : `http://8*8.1*9*1.1*6*1.2*35/moteur_iso/` REMOVE * (The tile juste on the right of the player is "non walkable".

I want to center the canva on the player.. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to do that, one way is to convert the isometric position of the player to a cartesian position (in pixel), then update the map's registration point, for example :

```
myMap.regX -= (myMap.player.posX - myMap.player.posY) * myMap.tilesHeight;
myMap.regY += (myMap.player.posX + myMap.player.posY) * myMap.tilesHeight/2;
```

If the player's position is x = 1 and y = 0, it will move the map 42px right and 21px up.
The player will be centered whatever his initial position.

Comment: Hum yeah, but i need to do that for each player's move (after my function moveplayer() when i click on a tile)... And with your example, it's...explosive :)

Comment: You asked how to center on a specific tile, so if you want to scroll the map when the player is moving, you need to adapt this code following each directions.